# Plurals ending in -es in words for which the last letter is not e

Tags: spelling, plural-forms

There are words, like *potato* where the plural form ends with *es* (*potatoes*). In which cases does a word have a plural ending with *es*, but the singular doesn't end with *e*?

Is there a rule for that, or do words like *potato* have an *irregular* plural?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16777/plural-of-nouns-or-plurals-of-noun

Comment: Sorry, but it is that question to duplicate this one. Look at when they have been asked.

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, I completely forgot to look. Here's another related question I just found: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33935/plural-form-of-word-which-ends-in-o

Comment: Still as before...

Comment: I'm not saying your question should be closed, I'm just linking them so that  people can find them from each other easily.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, _possible duplicate_ just mean a thing. Please edit the first comment, since they aren't duplicates; if they are, it's not this question that should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, it's too late to edit it. I didn't mean to cause confusion by the wording. And I found one more related question I'd like to link to, sorry: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29348/finger-tips-to-add-es-and-s-to-an-action-verb-to-convert-a-base-form-into-a/37568

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wikipedia gives a [pretty good overview](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural#Plurals_of_nouns_in_-o) of the rules. Based on the information there (don't cite it in a paper, but it's good enough for our purposes), nouns ending in -o are accompanied by nouns ending in a [sibilant sound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sibilant), which is far beyond the scope of this answer. But at any rate, here's the relevant sections from the Wilipedia article on English plurals:

> Where a singular noun ends in a sibilant sound —/s/, /z/, /ʃ/, /ʒ/, /tʃ/ or /dʒ/— the plural is formed by adding /ɨz/. The spelling adds -es, or -s if the singular already ends in -e:
>
> kiss  kisses  /ˈkɪsɨz/
> phase phases  /ˈfeɪzɨz/
> dish  dishes  /ˈdɪʃɨz/
>
> ...
>
> With nouns ending in o preceded by a consonant, the plural in many cases is spelled by adding -es (pronounced /z/):
>
> hero  heroes
> potato    potatoes
> volcano   volcanoes or volcanos
>
> However many nouns of foreign origin, including almost all Italian loanwords, add only -s:
>
> canto    cantos
> hetero    heteros
> photo photos

So in summary, add -es if:

- the word ends in -(consonant)o (usually), unless it isn't actually an English word and we're just borrowing it.
- the word ends in a certain kind of consonant sound, simplified to most uses of "s", "z", "ts", "sh", or "ch" (plus, I think, a couple others, but those cover most cases).