# Plural of Nouns or Plurals of Noun

Tags: nouns, plural-forms, suffixes

Mostly we add "s" to the noun to mean it as plural, but not for all of them. Is there any rule  for adding s / es / some thing else. I mentioned few words for Understanding.

Eg : Dog - Dogs Knife - Knives bus-buses.

And i also have a doubt, should i mention Plural or Plurals. Which is correct. 
 Eg : Plural of Nouns ? / Plurals of Noun ?

Comment: Because I could not find a good duplicate, I am answering this question. It is easy enough to search for "rules for forming plurals", which is how I found the info below.

Comment: Any hint for my second part of the question?

Answer (score 1):

Most Nouns: add s (lamps, dogs)
Noun Ending s, sh, ch, x or z: add es   (dresses, bosses, boxes)
Nouns ending consonant + o; add either s or es (There are no rules for this - you have to know.)    heroes, zeros, tomatoes
Nouns ending vowel + o:     add s   (patios, ratios)
Nouns ending consonant + y: change the y to an i and add es  (stories, pennies)
Nouns ending vowel + y: add s: (cays, donkeys)
Nouns ending f or fe:  -ves and/or s (There are no rules - you have to know.) dwarfs, hooves or hoofs
Exceptions
some nouns undergo a vowel or letters change (men, lice)
some nouns do not change at all (salmon, sheep)

You can read more [here](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/plurals_forming_table.htm)

Comment: The relevant [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plural) is very comprehensive.

Comment: Is it Plural or plurals. The above mentioned wikipedia article contains plurals. My doubt is- The meaning of plural is more than one in numeral, then what "plurals" used for?

Comment: @Ram: **"Plural"** is used for: a) a noun describing more than one thing ("dogs"), b) the name of the concept of such nouns in Linguistics (similarly to "possessive", 'pronoun', 'denominator' etc.)  **"Plurals"** refers to more than one (or all) nouns that are plural (as in meaning "a)")