# Plural form of the words which end in 'o'

Tags: plural-forms, spelling

Words ending in `-o` form plural by adding '-s'. In some resources I have read some of these words needs '-es' to make plural (e.g. echo, buffalo). However it seems both form of all such words (-s or -es) are recorded in dictionaries. So is it correct to form plural form of all o-ending word by only adding '-s'?

Comment: The only one I can think of is the letter *O*, whose plural requires an apostrophe *s*:  O's.

Comment: [plurals of words ending in o - slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/jomango/plurals-of-words-ending-in-o)

Comment: @Jim Plurals "requiring  an apostrophe?"  What do you mean? Reading that  I can't help hearing [Lynne Truss](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2006/dec/23/featuresreviews.guardianreview11) at the back of my mind... "The only illiteracy with apostrophes that stirs any sympathy in me is the greengrocer's variety."

Comment: @Laure From CGEL, p.1586: "Plurals with `'s`: An apostrophe may be used to separate the plural suffix from the base with letters, numbers (notably dates), symbols, abbreviations, and words used metalinguistically: (i) *p's and q's, 1960's, &'s, Ph.D.'s, if's and but's* (ii) *She got four A's and two B's.*  This practice is less common than it used to be; with dates and abbreviations ending in an upper case letter, the form without the apostrophe is now more usual: *in the 1960s, two candidates with Ph.D.s.*"

Comment: @Mina An excellent link!  It would make a great source for anyone who wanted to write an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to this excellent [presentaion](http://www.slideshare.net/jomango/plurals-of-words-ending-in-o), there are only a few words that **must** be pluriezed using only **-es**. Here is a list of such words:

- **potato**
- **tomato**
- **echo**
- **hero**
- veto
- embargo
- torpedo

(feel free to add any missing word to the list)

Answer (score 1):

There is some good guidance given by Oxford Dictionaries (OUP) [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/plurals-of-nouns) showing quite a number of examples.

The basic guidance is

> Nouns ending in -o can add either -s or -es in the plural, and some
> can be spelled either way.
>
> As a general rule, most nouns ending in -o add -s to make the plural:
>
> Those which have a vowel before the final -o always just add -s:
>
> a list of the most common nouns ending in -o that are **always** spelled with -es in the plural:
>
> ```
> singular    plural
> buffalo     buffaloes
> domino      dominoes
> echo        echoes
> embargo     embargoes
> hero        heroes
> mosquito    mosquitoes
> potato      potatoes
> tomato      tomatoes
> torpedo     torpedoes
> veto        vetoes
> ```
>
> some of the common nouns ending in -o that can be spelled with either -s or -es in the plural:
>
> ```
> singular      plural
> banjo         banjos or banjoes
> cargo         cargos or cargoes
> flamingo      flamingos or flamingoes
> fresco        frescos or frescoes
> ```

So there are some that 'require' the *-es* although there isn't a hard and fast 'rule' that you can apply.

Consider *zero* and *hero*; indistinguishable in their form and yet *zeros* is the standard plural of zero while *heroes* is the standard plural of hero.

"Plurals of nouns". Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/plurals-of-nouns (accessed September 21, 2014).

Comment: As I said in the question actually most of listed form are correct in both form.

Comment: @PHPst I think what Oxford Dictionaries are suggesting is that 'echos', 'heros', 'potatos', etc. are 'wrong' in whatever sense OD class them as wrong - perhaps 'wrong' means extremely uncommon in modern writing.

Comment: Please limit your answer to a list of such words ( 'echos', 'heros',… ) so I can mark your answer as accepted. The Mina's link also contain some of these words. Thanks.

Comment: see also my favorite unclear plural: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134628/plural-for-photo

Comment: "zeros" is the standard plural? You learn something new each day... Anyway, it seems that the "safe bet" is actually to always add -es.

Comment: @MaciejStachowski No, [both *zeros* and *zeroes* are standard](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33667102).  This is different than *hero*, for which [*heroes* is the standard plural](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=33667109).